# List-2 > sum13 coding bat problem: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, error-handling, break

I am having a problem with my code. The question is:

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.
From: https://codingbat.com/prob/p167025

```
def sum13(nums):
  if not nums:
    return 0
  for x in nums:
    if x == 13:
      break
    return sum(x)
    if 13 not in nums:
      return sums(nums)
```

The problem is that I cannot combine sum(x) and it gives out an error each time I try.
Can someone give a hint as to why?

Comment: you `return` on the first iteration

Comment: Changing it gives out an indentation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Misplaced `return` is one of the many problems here, but could be a good start to fix the logic. It is really hard to pinpoint a single issue that, once fixed, will produce the desired result. Instead, there is a general problem that the implementation does not relate to the task logic.

Normally, you decompose the problem to simpler bricks, somewhat like this:

```
def sum13(nums):
    # "Return the sum of the numbers in the array" 
    #  - let's iterate the array, increasing the sum
    res = 0
    previous_is_13 = False  # introduced later

    # "returning 0 for an empty array."
    # for loop will do nothing on empty arrays, as desired
    for i in nums:  
        # "Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count"
        # so, let's guard it with an if:
        if i == 13:
            # "numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count."
            # ok, let's set a flag to indicate that and clear it once we're past 13
            previous_is_13 = True
            continue

        if previous_is_13:
            previous_is_13 = False  # clear the flag and proceed to the next item
            continue
        res += i
    return res
```

Once you have the baseline solution, make it nicer, eg with an iterator:

```
def sum13(nums):
    return sum(value for i, value in enumerate(nums)
               if value!= 13 and (not i or nums[i-1] != 13))
```